EF Core throws a tracking exception when updating entities using AutoMapper
I'm using EF Core against a SQL Server database in a Blazor web app (on .NET 9) with Identity, and I am using AutoMapper to convert between the database entities and the DTOs that get sent out of and into the API.
I have ASP.NET Core Identity users represented by the following class. Note that in both entities and both DTOs shown here, I have removed the irrelevant properties for clarity:
public class User : IdentityUser {
  public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
  public virtual Company? Company { get; set; }
}

Users can be associated with a company or not. The Company class (again simplified) looks like this:
public class Company {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; } = [];
}

I use AutoMapper to create DTOs from the database entities. The DTOs are sent out from the API, and new/modified DTOs are received by the API, converted to entities and persisted to the database.
The DTO classes look like this...
public class CompanyDto {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public List<UserDto> Users { get; set; } = [];
}

public class UserDto {
  public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
  public string? CompanyName { get; set; }
}

My mapper config is as following...
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile {
  public AutoMapperProfile() {
    CreateMap<Company, CompanyDto>()
      .ReverseMap();
    CreateMap<User, UserDto>()
      .ReverseMap()
      // Next three rules to account for Identity storing the email four times
      .ForPath(entity => entity.NormalizedEmail, opt => opt.MapFrom(dto => dto.Email.ToUpper()))
      .ForPath(entity => entity.UserName, opt => opt.MapFrom(dto => dto.Email))
      .ForPath(entity => entity.NormalizedUserName, opt => opt.MapFrom(dto => dto.Email.ToUpper()));
  }
}

When a CompanyDto gets sent back to the API for saving, I attempt to fix up the users as follows...
public async Task SaveCompany(CompanyDto company) {
  if (company.Id == 0) {
    context.Companies.Add(mapper.Map<Company>(company));
  } else {
    Company? dbCompany = await context.Companies
      .Include(c => c.Users)
      .SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == company.Id);
    if (dbCompany is not null) {
      mapper.Map(company, dbCompany);

      foreach (UserDto user in company.Users) {
        User? dbUser = dbCompany.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.ID);

        if (dbUser is null) {
          dbCompany.Users.Add(mapper.Map<User>(user));
        } else {
          mapper.Map(user, dbUser);
        }
        context.Companies.Update(dbCompany);
      }
    }
  }
  await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

The issue I'm having is that whenever I try to save a company that has any associated users, I get an exception:

The instance of entity type 'User' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

This happens even if nothing has changed on the company, or on the user(s) associated with it.
I added the following code to see what was in the context, but nothing was output, implying that the context wasn't already tracking anything...
context.ChangeTracker
  .Entries()
  .Where(x => includeUnchanged || x.State != EntityState.Unchanged)
  .OrderBy(x => x.Entity.GetType().Name)
  .ForEach(x => {
    Console.WriteLine($"Entity ({x.Entity.GetType().Name}) has been {x.State.ToString()}");
  });

Is anyone able to explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Personally I recommend avoiding reverse mapping for entity<->DTO transformations when dealing with a related entity/DTO structure. When mapping from entity to DTO it is common/useful to flatten info from navigation properties, or build a DTO structure. Use explicit reverse maps to ignore these relationships so you instead have the individual DTO->Entity mappings so you can safely use .Map() through the navigation tree like you are doing. Note that if you are adding/removing related entities you will need to handle these manually.

Please share your Dto classes too.

@GuruStron I've added the DTOs, but as I said originally, they are basically mirror images of the entity classes, so I'm not sure how much they will help. Thanks

@StevePy Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Please can you clarify how you suggest I convert the DTOs to entities. I'm very new to AutoMapper, and indeed the idea of using DTOs, as all my work for years has been with Blazor server, where we can safely use entities all the way, as all the code is on the server. Thanks

SaveCompany is broken and not just due to AutoMapper, although that adds another layer of problems. DbContext is a Unit-of-Work and detects all changes in the objects it tracks. When you call SaveChanges all the changes will be persisted, not just company. That's not a bug. You don't need to manually search for entities, you need to only call SaveChanges when you're ready to commit all changes at the end of a scope

The Unit-of-Work, ie DbContext, already tracks dbCompany and the related objects. There's no reason to call Update on it. And once again, AutoMapper is fundamentally misused. At best it will modify all properties whether they need updating or not. You also need to consider what mapper.Map(company, dbCompany) will do to dbCompany.Users. Is it adding any missing objects? Overwriting the existing ones?

The error The instance of entity type 'User' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked suggests that the method's code is trying to add already existing DbCompany.User objects, which is exactly what would happen if  mapper.Map(company, dbCompany) modified DbCompany.Users to match Company.Users

What happens if you replace the entire SaveCompany method with just context.Update(mapper.Map<Company>(company)); ? AutoMapper is already mapping both Company and Users, maintaining their IDs. Update will automatically attach all reachable objects as either Added or Modified based on their PK values. This will update all properties, but so does the current code. You still have to move SaveChanges at the very end of the business transaction/scope.

@PanagiotisKanavos I was trying not to let the post get too long, and so omitted to mention that this was what I did originally. That gave the same exception, which is why I tried handling the user DTOs manually. Thanks anyway, any other suggestions?

You'd get that if the IDs weren't db-generated and had their default values. Given that you're using IdentityUser as if it was a normal domain class, that's probably the problem - the Id isn't database generated. IdentityUser is meant for use by the authentication middleware, not to be used as a generic Person or User. Company is an extra custom property for the actual root entity, IdentityUser, not the other way around

@PanagiotisKanavos Hmm, starting to understand slowly, but not sure how I'd fix this. I just added a user with the regular register page (so was added via the Identity code, not as a regular class), assigned it to a company and got the same error. How am I supposed to handle changes to users when they come in with the company DTO? Even if they are registered via Identity, I still need to be able to edit them as part of a company. Thanks again, if you can clarify this I'd be very grateful

To sum up explicit reverse mapping. .ReverseMap() is well suited to configuring Automapper to handle single-level entity<->DTO mappings, but will fall foul when trying to map DTO relationships back to entity relationships. In your case you are handling the Company.Users well enough, but Automapper will be stubbing it's toes with EF.
Explicitly configuring the reverse maps means removing .ReverseMap() and instead configuring a map explicitly from the DTOs back to the entity:
CreateMap<CompanyDTO, Company>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Users, opt => opt.Ignore());

This can also consider what properties should never be updated, and ignore those as well. Similar with the UserDTO mapping, ignoring any navigation properties.  When we get a CompanyDTO back from the view/consumer we will explicitly handle the users in the DTO to resolve those back into entities and update the overall relationships. Ideally I recommend avoiding "Upsert" operations. The front-end should determine "am I inserting, or am I updating" and call the appropriate endpoint. The two operations are different and should assert they are called with the info they need rather than adding conditional logic into one method to handle both scenarios and potentially hide bugs if an ID doesn't come across, or gets manipulated.
When updating a Company the Map(src, dest) call will ignore Users, so we can keep that relatively the same:
Company? dbCompany = await context.Companies
    .Include(c => c.Users)
    .SingleAsync(c => c.Id == company.Id);
mapper.Map(company, dbCompany);

However, when it comes to handling the users you need to carefully consider what the collection represents. For instance, are we adding and removing users that specifically belong to the company, or are we associating/de-associating user records with that company?  Assuming that users belong to a company rather than are associated with a company:
var newUsers = company.Users.Where(u => u.Id == 0).ToList();
var updatedUsers = company.Users.Where(u => u.Id != 0).ToList();
var updatedUserIds = updatedUsers.Select(u => u.Id).ToList();
var usersToRemove = dbCompany.Users.Where(u => !updatedUserIds.Contains(u.Id));

foreach(var user in usersToRemove)
   dbCompany.Users.Remove(user);


foreach (var user in updatedUsers) 
{
    User dbUser = dbCompany.Users.First(u => u.Id == user.ID);
    mapper.Map(user, dbUser);
}

foreach (var user in newUsers)
    dbCompany.Users.Add(mapper.Map<User>(user));

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

Here you want to be a bit more explicit with identifying the new records from the ones that may be updated, from the ones that would be removed and handle those scenarios. The original conditional logic could leave openings for scenarios where you end up mapping and instantiating a new entity where an existing row might already be tracked. Since we are dealing with tracked entities we do not want to call the Update() method for company or users. The change tracker should work perfectly fine when we call the Map(src, dest) to copy allowed values across from the DTO, as well as if we instantiate a new User and add it to the collection.
The above code would not work if users are instead associated with companies rather than in a more owned relationship. For instance if there is a many-to-many relationship where a user can be associated with multiple companies, or move between company records.
One other important change. When it comes to collection navigation properties in entities, you should always protect the setter so that a collection is never re-initialized/set.
public class Company 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; } = [];
}

No setter. If this breaks any code in your application, that code will very likely cause issues where change tracking links get broken. ObservableCollection is also a front-end servicing class, where entities should ideally focus solely on back-end data concerns rather than being bound to directly.

Wow, what a great answer! I need time to absorb it all, but I think I now understand how I should be working. Thanks very much, I'm going to try it out and will come back if I have any further questions.

OK, had time to absorb this and try it out and it all works fine. Thank you again for your excellent answer. I wish I could vote more than once!

I think the error might be caused by context.Update. In theory, the tracker should be able to identify it on its own when saving the project. Try removing the update and leaving only SaveChangesAsync.

Thanks for the suggestion, but I get the same exception without that line

That's not the only bug in the code. Calling Update on an already tracked entity will mark all reachable entities as Modified. Remove AutoMapper, the call to Update and move SaveChanges at the end of the operation/scope. Don't try to modify the change tracker, it's not broken

@PanagiotisKanavos I'm not trnyg to modify ChangeTracker, I'm trying to work out how to use it with AutoMapper. I'd be grateful if you (or anyone) could explain how I'm supposed to do this as I'm lost.
